# Need to calculate Sum in Excel based on condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an issue if somebody spare his time to have a look at the problem so it will be nice. Thanks in advance.

I am asking this part of question again as I am a bit confused in it.

I have different text in cells like yes, no, maybe. I need to find the total number of cells that contain these text in a specific cell under result box but what I want to do is that

I want to calculate Yes =1, No = 0, Maybe = 0.01.
Means I need to find yes, no and maybe but I want their sum/average at the end in this form.

Please see the picture.
[image]

In Picture I have 2 Yes and 3 maybe and 2 No so I want to get like 2.03.
I am using the below mentioned formula

```
=COUNTIF(E5:AHI5, "yes") + COUNTIF(E5:AHI5, "no") + COUNTIF(F5:AHI5, "maybe")
```

But it only counts total number of values for yes, no, maybe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Then multiply the returns of their countif.  And since you are wanting 0 for no it is not needed:

```
=(COUNTIF(E5:AHI5, "yes")*1) + (COUNTIF(F5:AHI5, "maybe")*.01)
```

Comment: thanks a lot man for quick and perfect reply. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
=COUNTIF(E5:AHI5, "yes") + COUNTIF(F5:AHI5, "maybe")*.01
```